# The component for route must be a react component Search : MyScreen

Tags: react-navigation

### The component for route 'FilmDetail' must be a React Component

I'm trying to use `react-navigation` but I can't get it to work. I've tried removing brackets while importing and can still reproduce the error:

**Navigaton.js**

```
import React from 'react' 
import { StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import {  createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import Search from '../Components/Search'
import FilmDetail from '../Components/FilmDetail'
import Favorites from '../Components/Favorites'

const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Rechercher'
    }
  },
  FilmDetail: {
    screen: FilmDetail
  }
})

const MoviesTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Search: {
      screen: SearchStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: () => { 
          return <Image
            source={require('../Images/ic_search.png')}
            style={styles.icon}/> 
        }
      }
    },
    Favorites: {
      screen: Favorites,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: () => {
          return <Image
            source={require('../Images/ic_favorite.png')}
            style={styles.icon}/>
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeBackgroundColor: '#DDDDDD', 
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', 
      showLabel: false, 
      showIcon: true 
    }
  }
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30
  }
})

export default createAppContainer(MoviesTabNavigator)
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Store from './Store/configureStore'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <Navigation/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

**FilmDetail.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, Image, Button ,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import   {getImageFromApi} from '../API/TMDBApi'
import getFilmDetailFromApi  from '../API/TMDBApi'

import moment from 'moment'
import numeral from 'numeral'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class FilmDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      film: undefined,
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getFilmDetailFromApi(this.props.navigation.state.params.idFilm).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        film: data,
        isLoading: false
      })
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate : ")
    console.log(this.props.favoritesFilm)
  }

  _displayLoading() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading_container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  _toggleFavorite() {
    const action = { type: "TOGGLE_FAVORITE", value: this.state.film }
    this.props.dispatch(action)
  }
  _displayFavoriteImage() {
    var sourceImage = require('../Images/ic_favorite_border.png')
    if (this.props.favoritesFilm.findIndex(item => item.id === this.state.film.id) !== -1) {
      // Film dans nos favoris
      sourceImage = require('../Images/ic_favorite.png')
    }
    return (
      <Image
        style={styles.favorite_image}
        source={sourceImage}
      />
    )
  }

  _displayFilm() {
    const { film } = this.state
    if (film != undefined) {
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview_container}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{uri: getImageFromApi(film.backdrop_path)}}
          />
          <Text style={styles.title_text}>{film.title}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.favorite_container} onPress={() => this._toggleFavorite()}>{this._displayFavoriteImage()}</TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.description_text}>{film.overview}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Sorti le {moment(new Date(film.release_date)).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Note : {film.vote_average} / 10</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Nombre de votes : {film.vote_count}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Budget : {numeral(film.budget).format('0,0[.]00 $')}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Genre(s) : {film.genres.map(function(genre){
              return genre.name;
            }).join(" / ")}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Companie(s) : {film.production_companies.map(function(company){
              return company.name;
            }).join(" / ")}
          </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        {this._displayLoading()}
        {this._displayFilm()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  loading_container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  scrollview_container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  image: {
    height: 169,
    margin: 5
  },
  title_text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 35,
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: '#000000',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  description_text: {
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    color: '#666666',
    margin: 5,
    marginBottom: 15
  },
  default_text: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
  },favorite_container: {
    alignItems: 'center'
},favorite_image: {
  width: 40,
  height: 40
}
})

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    favoritesFilm: state.favoritesFilm
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FilmDetail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by changing my "react-navigation": "^1.6.1" to "react-navigation": "^4.3.9" and instead of using @react-navigation/bottom-tabs i tried using react-navigation-tabs

Answer (score 0):

Your displayLoading and displayFilm functions need to return null. Currently they only return if the happy path is followed, but that can lead to weird stuff happening if they don't return null for the other paths where they shouldn't display themselves.

I'm not sure if that will fix your error or not, I am not seeing anything else sticking out to me, but I would implement that and see if your issue goes away.

If that doesn't work, try not using React-Navigation for a second and just import/render the FilmDetail component by itself to see if a different error comes up that may be the underlying issue.

If not let me know and I'll look again.

Comment: Thank u for replying but none of this solutions fix my error

Comment: Do you have the same error when you just used the FilmDetail without the navigation?

Comment: No when i tried removing the file navigation.js everything worked fine

Comment: What version of react navigation are you using?

Comment: "react-navigation": "^1.6.1"